# UNIX script able to run manually but not via crontab

Tags: unix

I have created unix script to connect to Oracle Database and pull some data. When i run the script manually, it works perfectly fine but when it runs the cron, it is throwing SQL error.

Cron entry:

```
05 14 * * mon-fri /home/test.sh >& /home/test.log
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

. /home/common_profile

log_Path="/home/Logs"

SQLfile1="/home/Sql/Query.sql"

database=$ORA_SVR

user=$ORA_ID

passwd=$ORA_PWD

echo "---------------------"

echo "Connecting to Database : $database"

echo "spool $log_Path/SQL_Output.log

          select count(*) from table where lbd='20180221';
          spool off
          quit" > $SQLfile1

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S -L $user/$passwd@$database @$SQLfile1

cat $log_Path/SQL_Output.log
```

The problem is $log_Path/SQL_Output.log is not getting updated and instead shows the some SQL errors.

I have checked ORACLE_HOME as well and its pointing correctly. Please advise

Comment: try simplyfing removing echo and variables, just: spool file.log. What you need to achieve before redirecting to a file is that the SQL is executed correctly.

Comment: I did try that but still facing the same issue. by default we use ksh. do i need to explicitly mention ksh in the cron command?